# Ask LuaLaTeX to ignore an active catcode previously written into aux file by pdflatex

Tags: luatex, babel, auxiliary-files, catcodes

I'm writing a package that loads `babel` and which users might run under either `pdflatex` or `lualatex`. When babel's `french` option is loaded, ":" is made active; and `pdflatex` writes the following into the `.aux` file:

```
\catcode `:\active
```

This is all fine for `pdflatex`.  However, if a user (for some reason) decides to starting running with `lualatex`, the existing `.aux` file is read, and an error is reported when subsequent lines of the `.aux` file contain ":". For example,

```
\newlabel{eqn:1}{{1}{1}}
```

results in

```
Undefined control sequence. 
<argument> r@eqn:
      1
```

One can just trash the `.aux` file and go again, but I'd like to prevent the message from appearing at all.

Is there a means of telling `lualatex` what to do with this active character (say, read it as ":")?

I'd thought of a construction such as

```
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\iflualatex
   \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
   \AtEndPreamble{\catcode`:<someaction>}
\fi
```

but I am not sure what **someaction** ought to be...

This MWE illustrates the problem in a single document:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
Some English. \foreignlanguage{french}{Cette théorie formera désormais une des branches les plus importantes de la physique générale}. More English.

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:1}
f(x) = Ax
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using luatex, you can write a line to the aux file so the file will not be read if you are using luatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\ifx\directlua\undefined
\AtBeginDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\detokenize{%
 \ifx\directlua\undefined\else\endinput\fi}}}
\fi
\makeatother
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
Some English. \foreignlanguage{french}{Cette théorie formera désormais une des branches les plus importantes de la physique générale}. More English.

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:1}
f(x) = Ax
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

so use pdflatex and the aux file will have the line

```
\ifx \directlua \undefined \else \endinput \fi
```

which does nothing while you use pdftex, but will stop the file being read the first time you use luatex.

Comment: Brilliant -- that fully resolves my problem!  Thank you, David.